# style.display помогите с функцией

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Форма:

```
if ($page_1=="v6")
{
    $err=$my->out_branch_read("./project/".$name .".txt", "Cleaning_dir");
    if ($my->out_branch_read=="new") {
        echo "<p style='margin:20px'> <input type='radio' name='cleaning_dir' value='new' checked onclick='return ShowArea(this.form, 146)'> Выгрузить только новые изменения<br>";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='cleaning_dir' value='load' onclick='return ShowArea(this.form, 145)'> Выгрузить рабочую копию полностью";
    } else {
        echo "<p style='margin:20px'> <input type='radio' name='cleaning_dir' value='new' onclick='return ShowArea(this.form, 146)'> Выгрузить только новые изменения<br>";
        echo "<input type='radio' name='cleaning_dir' value='load' checked onclick='return ShowArea(this.form, 145)'> Выгрузить рабочую копию полностью";
        $err=$my->out_branch_read("./project/".$name .".txt", "Flag");
        if ($my->out_branch_read=="true")
            echo "<div id=cleaning style='display:block;margin:20px 0 0 50px'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='flag' value='true' checked onclick='return ShowArea(this.form, 145)'> Предварительная очистка рабочей копии </div>";
        else echo "<div id=cleaning style='display:block;margin:20px 0 0 50px'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='flag' value='true' onclick='return ShowArea(this.form, 145)'> Предварительная очистка рабочей копии </div>";
    }
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выбираю radio2, то выпадает флажок, который можно выбрать. Сохраняю это дело и в *.txt записывается: 
 
 Cleaning_dir=load 
Flag=true 
 
При этом можно кликать на radio2 и список будет то сворачиваться, то открываться.
Но если, в txt-шник было сохранено значение первого radio, т.е. Cleaning_dir=new, то при нажатие на radio2 - чекбокс не выпадает, то есть, не сохранив значение radio2 - нельзя догадаться, что там ещё и чекбокс есть.
Как обработка этого события выглядит:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function ShowArea(form, value) { 
  var cleaning=document.getElementById("cleaning");

  if (value==145) {
    if (cleaning.style.display=="none") {
      cleaning.style.display="block";
      form.сleaning_dir='load';
    } else {
      cleaning.style.display="block";
      form.сleaning_dir='load';
    }
  }

  if (value==146) {
    cleaning.style.display="none";
    form.сleaning_dir='new';
  }   
}
```

Нужно, чтобы чекбокс открывался всегда, несмотря на то, что даже в txt-шнике значение new! 
Помогите!
Может с block и none напитала.

Comment: Вам нужно выводить полный html независимо от содержимого txt файла. Отличаться должны display значения. Сейчас же у вас просто нет этого checkbox'a на клиенте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо навести капитальный порядок в этом коде:

- атрибут "name" у чекбокса должен отличаться от "name" радио-кнопок
- разделить PHP и HTML код
- сразу вывести весь html-код данного участка (обе радио-кнопки и чекбокс)
- состояние радио-кнопок и чекбокса сохранять отдельными значениями

Приблизительный пример:

```
$cleaning_dir_new = false;
$cleaning_dir_load = false;
$cleaning_dir_clear = false;
$my->out_branch_read('./project/'.$name .'.txt', 'Cleaning_dir');
if ($my->out_branch_read=='new') {
    $cleaning_dir_new = true;
}else {
    $cleaning_dir_load = true;
    $my->out_branch_read('./project/'.$name .'.txt', 'Flag');
    if ($my->out_branch_read=='true') $cleaning_dir_clear = true;
}
if ($cleaning_dir_new) $cleaning_dir_new = 'checked';
if ($cleaning_dir_load) $cleaning_dir_load = 'checked';
if ($cleaning_dir_clear) $cleaning_dir_clear = 'checked';
```

---

```
<p style="margin:20px">
    <input type="radio" name="cleaning_dir" value="new" <?echo $cleaning_dir_new;?>>
    Выгрузить только новые изменения
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="cleaning_dir" value="load" <?echo $cleaning_dir_load;?>>
    Выгрузить рабочую копию полностью
    <div id=cleaning style="display:block;margin:20px 0 0 50px">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cleaning_dir-clear" value="true" <?echo $cleaning_dir_clear;?>>
        Предварительная очистка рабочей копии
    </div>
    <div id=cleaning style="display:block;margin:20px 0 0 50px">
</p>
```

Будет лучше, если с начала решить задачу, что бы правильно были сохранения состояний радио-кнопок и чекбокса. А уже после можно реализовать действие, которые скрывает/показывает чекбокс.

Comment: "name" у чекбоксов "flag", а у радио-кнопок "cleaning_dir". Несмотря на кашу в коде, состояния сохраняются верно. Иначе, ни один бы командник не запустился бы в дальнейшем.) Сайт не мой и там всё реализовано в такой вот "каше". Я просто пытаюсь понять, почему чекбокс не видно, когда в txt-шнике значение от 1-ой, т.е. "new" радио-кнопки, когда там "load" от второй кнопки - всё отлично.

Comment: это не моё упрямство. Я уже давно предложила потихонечку начать переписывать этот сайт. Но руководство пока против. Те страницы, которые я добавляю - стараюсь делать грамотно. Я впервые занимаюсь web-ом. А человека, который всё тут наворотил - вообще не видела.)

Comment: Потому что у Вас условие выводит только две радио-кнопки без чекбокса, когда NEW http://i.imgur.com/16kIn9A.png

Comment: Это условие надо убрать и сразу выводить обе радио-кнопки и чекбокс

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.)